# how to jump to a whole frame in beamer

Tags: beamer, hyperref

I try to use `\hyperlink` command to jump between frames, while it's not like the kind of jump as in the `tableofcontents`. I want to jump to an entire frame, not in the middle of a frame. Can anyone help me fix this out?

Answer (score 1):

If you count how many slides your target frame has, you can select to which slide within a frame you'd like to jump like this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{frame}
    \hyperlink{foo<2>}{jump}
\end{frame} 

\begin{frame}[label=foo]
    abc\pause def
\end{frame} 
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks, it helps a lot

Comment: @BillWang You're welcome!